# Nginx: pass through HTTPS to different targets based on location

Tags: docker, nginx, https, nginx-reverse-proxy

I'm a complete noob to nginx reverse proxy, so forgive me if this question is stupid. My situation is that I run multiple docker containers that manage HTTPS certificates themselves and I need reverse proxy to access them from browser. The problem is that certificates need to be managed from within those containers, not from nginx reverse proxy.

I Googled and tried lots of things and only thing that seem to work is to pass through stream directly to container's local address.

```
events { }

stream {
  server {
    listen 443;
    listen [::]:443;

    proxy_pass 10.0.0.1:443;  
  }
}
```

When I'm working with stream (that is - as far as I know - needed for this pass through), there's no way I know, how to differentiate the destinations I'm trying to reach.

I need configuration that would enable me to do something like this:

```
https://mail.example.com --> proxy_pass 10.0.0.1
https://mail.example.com --> proxy_pass 10.0.0.1
https://www.example.com --> proxy_pass 10.0.0.2 
https://foo.example.com --> proxy_pass 10.0.0.2
```

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: i'd advise reading the docs for location and server blocks. what you want to do is have multiple server blocks with server_name directives inside. there is no such thing as a absolute solution to this and everyone will show you different configuration examples. you should just familiarise yourself with already existing configuration examples and the docs to learn how nginx works. i could spent time to write a possible configuration for you. since that's not billable nor the point of stackoverflow, i'd suggest doing what i just suggested to find a solution. this is trivial stuff.

Answer (score 1):

What are you looking for is to how to setup SSL pass-through proxy (TCP forwarding) and use SNI information for the routing. I'm not sure that you can do it using nginx, because in nginx there is no way to pipe the connection using SNI information (as far as I know).

I tried to create a HAproxy configuration with docker-compose for this and seems that it's working as you want. I used docker-compose to run all apps in one network, so you can access other services based on their name in the docker-compose.

*./docker-compose.yml*

```
version: '3'

services:

  proxy:
    image: haproxy:1.9.8
    ports:
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - "./haproxy:/usr/local/etc/haproxy"

  mail:
    image: mail    # replace it with your app image, it must have port 443 open
    ports:
      - "445:443"  # this port mapping is for debug purposes only, remove it after

  foo:
    image: foo
    ports:
      - "446:443"
```

*./haproxy/haproxy.cfg*

```
defaults
  maxconn 1000
  mode http
  log global
  option dontlognull # bind *:443 ssl crt .
  timeout http-request 5s
  timeout connect 5000
  timeout client 2000000 # ddos protection
  timeout server 2000000 # stick-table type ip size 100k expire 30s store conn_cur

frontend https
  bind *:443
  mode tcp
  option tcplog
  tcp-request inspect-delay 5s
  tcp-request content accept if { req_ssl_hello_type 1 }
  use_backend foo-servers if { req.ssl_sni -i foo.example.com }
  use_backend mail-servers if { req.ssl_sni -i mail.example.com }

backend foo-servers
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server server1 foo:443       # You can use service name from docker-compose here

backend mail-servers
  mode tcp
  balance roundrobin
  option ssl-hello-chk
  server server1 mail:443
```

Then you can just run it:

```
$ docker-compose up
```

After then ensure that your app is working:

```
$ curl -k https://localhost:445
mail service
$ curl -k https://localhost:446
foo service
```

And finally we can test our proxy:

```
$ curl -k https://mail.example.com
mail service
$ curl -k https://foo.example.com
foo service
```

Note: to make it work I added mail.example.com and foo.example.com to /etc/hosts

```
127.0.0.1   mail.example.com
127.0.0.1   foo.example.com
```

---

PS. Here's the Dockerfile for "foo" application (the same config is for mail):

*./Dockerfile*

```
FROM nginx:latest
COPY ssl.conf                   /etc/nginx/conf.d/ssl.conf
COPY mail.html                  /usr/share/nginx/html/index.html
COPY certs/mail.example.com.crt /etc/nginx/certs/
COPY certs/mail.example.com.key /etc/nginx/certs/
COPY certs/dhparam.pem          /etc/nginx/certs/
```

*./ssl.conf*

```
server {
    listen 443 http2 ssl;

    ssl_certificate       /etc/nginx/certs/mail.example.com.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key   /etc/nginx/certs/mail.example.com.key;
    ssl_dhparam           /etc/nginx/certs/dhparam.pem;

    root /usr/share/nginx/html;

    location / {
    }
}
```

Create self-signed certificate:

```
$ openssl req -x509 -nodes -days 365 -newkey rsa:2048 -keyout certs/foo.example.com.key -out certs/foo.example.com.crt
$ openssl dhparam -out certs/dhparam.pem 2048
```

Build image:

```
$ docker build -t foo .
```